# Rendering layers of multiple CRS systems(EPSG: 4326 and EPSG:3857)

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, rendering, qgsmapcanvas

I m trying to render layers of multiple CRS systems on QgsmapCanvas using QGIS3 C++ APIs.

When I render multiple layers of only one CRS( like `EPSG:4326` ) at a time, everything works fine. But when I render a layer of `EPSG:3857` or any other CRS, after rendering one layer of `EPSG:4326`, then the second layer does not appear on the canvas.

My code for rendering multiple CRS systems file :

```
 settings= mMapCanvas->mapSettings();
 auto layers= mMapCanvas->layers();
 settings.setLayers(layers);
 settings.setDestinationCrs(layers[0]->crs());
 mMapCanvas->refreshAllLayers();
```

What should I do before rendering any layer on the map canvas?